# How to fix theme, that is inserting paragraph tags throughout the in nex-forms

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My theme is inserting paragraph tags throughout the in nex-forms, that I use for survey (plugin Nex forms). That theme uses Rapid composer, and the problem only appears if I paste the form shortcode through that editor. Right now the main problem is with the radio buttons.

```
<p></p>
<div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright blue has-pretty-child">
<p>
<span class="input-label radio-label" style="color: rgb(68, 68,  68);">Да</span>
<label class="radio-inline" for="смс-сообщение_было_получено_нет">
</p>
```

That is how it should look like:

```
<div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright blue has-pretty-child">
<span class="input-label radio-label" style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Да</span>
<label class="radio-inline" for="смс-сообщение_было_получено_нет">
```

Here is the link, if needed: https://kyrier.ru/otsenka-kachestva/

I've tried plugins, it doesn't help. So, I've added this to functions.php

```
function remove_empty_p( $content ) {
$content = force_balance_tags( $content );
$content = preg_replace( '#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content );
$content = preg_replace( '~\s?<p>(\s| )+</p>\s?~', '', $content );
return $content;
```

}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_p', 20, 1);

It worked, but it gives me this at the top of the form:

```
    function test_run_nf_conditional_logic26896505(){

} jQuery(document).ready( function() {

jQuery(document).on('change', '#nex-forms input, #nex-forms select, #nex-forms textarea', function() { test_run_nf_conditional_logic26896505() } ); } );
```

Comment: you might try looking for a wordpress plugin that disables autoformatting and insertion of p and br tags.